# Transforming and repeating multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has two IDs within it named FamilyID and PersonID. I need to be able to repeat these rows with all combinations, as the below screenshot shows noting that each of the numbers get an extra row.

[image]

Here is some SQL to create the table with some sample data. There is no set number of occurrences that could occur.

Anyone aware of how we could be achieved?

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStackOverflow
(
    FamilyID int,
    PersonID int
)

insert into #TempStackOverflow
(
    FamilyID,
    PersonID
)
select
    1012,
    1
union
select
    1013,
    1
union
select
    1014,
    1
union
select
    1015,
    2
union
select
    14774,
    3
union
select
    1019,
    5
```

Comment: You could do something like a self-join with a CTE, I suppose. e.g. `WITH CTE AS (SELECT FamilyID, PersonID FROM myTable UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT PersonID, PersonID FROM myTable) SELECT C1.FamilyID, C2.FamilyID FROM CTE AS C1 JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C1.PersonID = C2.PersonID AND C1.FamilyID <> C2.FamilyID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you need some sort of a complete list of matches within groups, but honestly, it would be much better if you would explain the business context, using plain English, in the first place.

The following query seems to produce your sample result:

```
with cte as (
    select a.FamilyID, a.PersonID, a.PersonID as [GroupId] from #TempStackOverflow a
    union all
    select b.PersonID, b.FamilyID, b.PersonID from #TempStackOverflow b
)
select distinct c.FamilyID, s.PersonID
from cte c
    inner join cte s on s.GroupId = c.GroupId
where c.FamilyID != s.PersonID;
```

Comment: Thanks Roger. Going with your answer as the accepted solution as it has the best performance of the proposed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest version I can come up with that groups the items by PersonId, as you do above. Obviously if you don't want that, then you can remove the outer query.

```
SELECT FamilyId,
    PersonID
FROM (
    SELECT FamilyId, PersonId, PersonID as SortBy
    FROM #TempStackOverflow t1
    UNION
    SELECT PersonId, FamilyId, PersonId as SortBy
    FROM #TempStackOverflow t1
    UNION
    SELECT t1.FamilyID, t2.FamilyID, t1.PersonID as SortBy
    FROM #TempStackOverflow t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TempStackOverflow t2
        ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID
    WHERE t1.FamilyID != t2.FamilyID
    ) as Src
ORDER BY SortBy
```

Comment: Thanks Laughing Vergil. That does the trick perfectly. Up-voted your post, but going with the other option as it runs a lot faster.